# Can somebody show me a working gettxoutproof / verifytxoutproof pair?

Tags: bitcoin-core, bitcoin-cli

Can somebody please show me a working `gettxoutproof` / `verifytxoutproof` pair, I am looking for the input used on bitcoin-cli or console window in Bitcoin Core to make this happen, and the outputs.

For example, TXID: `D97A21CF46FD5AFB0BF9EA4237BC4BF5C84E8B47D38D1EEE2BBEB5C0F8A1C625` is included in block `0000000000000a3290f20e75860d505ce0e948a1d1d846bec7e39015d242884b`

The input to `gettxoutproof` should include the txid and the blockhash.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Given:

- txid: `3bdb32c04e10b6c399bd3657ef8b0300649189e90d7cb79c4f997dea8fb532cb`
- blockhash: `0000000000000000007962066dcd6675830883516bcf40047d42740a85eb2919`

With these, you can create a proof and verify it like so:

```
$ bitcoin-cli gettxoutproof "[\"3bdb32c04e10b6c399bd3657ef8b0300649189e90d7cb79c4f997dea8fb532cb\"]" 0000000000000000007962066dcd6675830883516bcf40047d42740a85eb2919
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
$ bitcoin-cli verifytxoutproof 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
[
   "3bdb32c04e10b6c399bd3657ef8b0300649189e90d7cb79c4f997dea8fb532cb"
]
```

Comment: Note that `>bitcoin-cli help gettxoutproof` says that you need to maintain a transaction index, using the -txindex command line option or
specify the block in which the transaction is included manually (by blockhash) for this command to operate reliably. I do not believe it operates if the transaction is in a pruned block.